# append Json object in a url in nodejs

Tags: node.js, httprequest

How to append Json object in a url using request module.(npm).

```
  https://secure.paytm.in/oltp/HANDLER_INTERNAL/REFUND?JsonData={"MID":"QUIbcctvgfvfgfvgdf","ORDERID":"6d22b2c2-a543-459c-9f83-cbeeb7efcd82","TXNTYPE":"REFUND","REFUNDAMOUNT":"1","TXNID":"20180508111212800110168695724952384","REFID":"55","CHECKSUM":"Z%2BLCp3lqjkZWHLGX%2BNtPWJpP7srhMT47Cjqj8yMg1LoQgVJ3QpqbXZAAupXCppcLIp0Zm0cIMSvmKy%2Bd0KUm8E9iUI4on37xUfic6n6um5Q%3D"}
```

The above mentioned url is a sample which i want to use using request module using POST method. Here i have mentioned TXNID and CHECKSUM and REFID values but when i want to use the request module i want to ftech those values from an object Like an object given below

```
                 JsonDat={
                   "MID":"QUhtvrrytcc",
                    "ORDERID": "6d22b2c2-a543-459c-9f83-cbeeb7efcd82",
                     "TXNID": "20180508111212800110168695724952384",
                      "TXNTYPE":"REFUND",
                      "REFUNDAMOUNT":"1",
                     "REFID": "12345",
                      "CHECKSUM": refundchecksum[socket.request.user.user_id]

                  }
```

Comment: Try stringify and then append it

Comment: ok. .how to append it?

Comment: `request(\`http://yourLink?jsonData=${JSON.stringify(json)}\`, function(){})`

Comment: BTW it's a post/get request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi you can stringify json object check below -

```
var url = "https://secure.paytm.in/oltp/HANDLER_INTERNAL/REFUND?JsonData=" + JSON.stringify(JsonDat);
```